Pattern match where type has constructors
I'm using a 3rd party library which has the following types:
data ServicesRequest req contentType res accept = ServicesRequest
  { rMethod  :: NH.Method   
  , rUrlPath :: [BCL.ByteString] 
  , rParams   :: Params 
  , rAuthTypes :: [P.TypeRep] 
  }

I'm trying to extract the req from a list of ServicesRequest (serviceRequests), similar to this:
let reqs = map (\(ServicesRequest req contentType res accept) -> req) serviceRequests 

Unfortunately, this produces a list of NH.Method's, the first constructor to ServiceRequest.
I've tried different variations to get the `req', but they all give 'parse error in pattern':
let reqs = map (\(ServicesRequest{} req contentType res accept) -> req) serviceRequests 

let reqs = map (\((ServicesRequest _ _ _ _) req contentType res accept) -> req) serviceRequests 


How can I pattern match on the req without it being confused as rMethod constructor?

You looking the type constructor. It's not clear how those parameters are used with the data constructor. What library are you using?

This looks like an example of a phantom type.

There is one type here, parameterized by 4 separate types. There is also one data constructor, parameterized on 4 other types unrelated to the 4 type variables defined by the type constructor. You could have a value of type ServicesRequest Int Int Int Int, for example, and have no Int values present in that value.

@Neil For me it looks like req is a type parameter. Is it possible to pattern match a type? I suppose not. Otherwise it looks strange to me. May be you want to declare ServicesRequest without type parameter data ServicesRequest = ServicesRequest { ... }. Additionally, may be the value req is just missing in your data declaration of ServicesRequest. Hard to see without more details: Where is the data declaration coming from. Is it complete? How are the field inside declared, e.g. Params. Please, clarify. Thank you.

When using a data type like data T a = K Int we find the constructor K always containing an integer, and that there's no value of type a occurring anywhere inside K. We say a is phantom. Since a value of type T String contains an int, and not a string, there is no meaningful function T String -> String, but only T String -> Int. In your case, req is a phantom, used only to tag the type during compilation, but there is no value of type req that can be extracted. I'd read your library docs to understand how that tag is used, maybe there's some useful function.

Thanks @chi and @chepner, after reading about it, req is indeed a phantom type. The library is generated code by the openapi haskell client generator, and it doesn't create any functions that are useful for getting at req. Since we can't match on req, I'll see if there is another approach I can use in the code.


I'm trying to extract the req from a list of ServicesRequest

There are no reqs in a ServicesRequest, so this isn't possible.

Is it possible to pattern match a type?

By default, there's no pattern matching at the type level. You can certainly write types that ensure that the req type is the same one as in a ServicesRequest -- just use the same name in both places you want it. For example:
constrainedId :: ServicesRequest req contentType res accept -> req -> req
constrainedId _ = id

Such restricted types can be useful. Check out ScopedTypeVariables if you need to annotate types inside the body of your function with a req from the top-level type annotation.
For more advanced uses, type families offer something that looks a bit like type-level pattern matching. For example:
type family ReqFromSR a where
    ReqFromSR (ServicesRequest req contentType res accept) = req

You could then write approximately the same type for constrainedId in a slightly more compact form:
constrainedId :: sr -> ReqFromSR sr -> ReqFromSR sr
-- OR
constrainedId :: ReqFromSR sr ~ req => sr -> req -> req
constrainedId _ = id

